# How to add a recently added C# Class library to the existing Git repository that the solution is already connected to

Tags: c#, git, console-application

I'm new to using GitHub and Git , When I first created my console app I created a git repository and hit commit and push , it works fine for the console app which was present in the time of creating the git repository , but when I added a new class library(CalculatorLibrary) and started writing code in it , I realized the Changes are not detected in the git changes section and it doesn't exist in the GitHub copy of the repository either, Plz help me !

[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjGNO.png)

[Local Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQtLA.png)

Comment: Hi, taking for granted you are using VS you have to open the GIT changes menu on the right side, commit new changes and then them push to your repository. Here's a link to help you [GIT](https://yourbrainoncomputers.com/using-git-with-visual-studio-2019-the-ultimate-guide/)

Answer (score 2):

I can see on your local repository folder pic that the Calculator Library is actually outside of your solution folder(ConsoleApp1 folder, which contains the calculator.cs project). To have them commited easily to the git all projects that are part of a solution should be under that solution folder. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You created your Git repository inside the Calculator folder. Which means git keeps track of only the files and directories which are inside this folder.
If you want to track CalculatorLibrary you should have created a git repository one level higher. (which you could do by .git folder and creating a new repository in the folder that contains these two libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, so I had to uncheck this box when creating the initial solution/project, then when I add another project to the solution for example a class library, it will be tracked in GIT:

[image]

[image]